# Run tubeless tire on standard rim as long as I use a tube?

Tags: tire, tubeless

I have some standard rims and I (accidentally) bought tubeless tires. As long as I use rim tape and a tube, can I run these tubeless tires? I know I won't be able to run low tire pressure. But if the tube holds all the pressure is there any danger of the bead unseating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, no problem. It's conceivable there could be some kind of exception someday, but so far not that I've seen or heard of.

Comment: Although it might be hard work to get them on the rim and off in case of a puncture because they have tighter beads. Better use anti puncture milk in the tubes.

Comment: They don't necessarily have tighter beads. I.e., the actual diameter of the bead is not necessarily smaller.

Comment: I found these specific tires to be quite easy to get on/off. I could put them on by hand. But I could see that being different for different tires.